# aerospike on openvz 2core 4Gb ram doesn't start and doesn't give errors

Tags: vps, solid-state-drive, aerospike, openvz

after installation without any trouble I've started aerospike on a openvz vps with 2cores and 4gb ram.
this is the result:

```
root@outland:~# /etc/init.d/aerospike start
 * Start aerospike:  asd  [OK]
```

then check for running asd:

```
root@outland:~# /etc/init.d/aerospike status
 * Halt aerospike:  asd                                                  [fail]
```

what is going wrong?

adding logs:

```
Mar 03 2015 15:17:57 GMT: INFO (config): (cfg.c::3033) system file descriptor limit: 100000, proto-fd-max: 15000

Mar 03 2015 15:17:57 GMT: WARNING (cf:misc): (id.c::249) Tried eth,bond,wlan and list of all available interfaces on device.Failed to retrieve physical address with errno 19 No such device


Mar 03 2015 15:17:57 GMT: CRITICAL (config): (cfg.c:3363) could not get unique id and/or ip address

Mar 03 2015 15:17:57 GMT: WARNING (as): (signal.c::120) SIGINT received, shutting down

Mar 03 2015 15:17:57 GMT: WARNING (as): (signal.c::123) startup was not complete, exiting immediately
```

Comment: Did you check the logs at /var/log/aerospike/aerospike.log for errors?

Comment: checked now. added logs to question. I don't know what is wrong. if it's a container config problem or aerospike config problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your config problem

```
Mar 03 2015 15:17:57 GMT: WARNING (cf:misc): (id.c::249) Tried eth,bond,wlan and list of all available interfaces on device.Failed to retrieve physical address with errno 19 No such device

Mar 03 2015 15:17:57 GMT: CRITICAL (config): (cfg.c:3363) could not get unique id and/or ip address
```

Basically the vps has a non standard interface name.

The solution is to add your interface name as `network-interface-name` to the config.

http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/troubleshoot/startup/#problem-with-network-interface

Which OS are your using btw?